# appending to a filename w/ a date from within a cron job

Tags: bash, cron

I have read that we can determine the current date in Bash with the date command like follows:

```
NOW=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")
```

In my crontab I append logs to files, and wanted to use this to put dates at the end of my file names, like follows:

```
cd /x/y/z/ && mycommand &>> /x/y/z/logs/mylog_$(date '+%Y%m%d').txt
```

However, this doesn't work as expected. I get the below error message, which I don't understand... I have no idea what it's referring to. I'm pretty new to using cron jobs.

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Comment: Make things easier for you: Don't try to force everything into one line for cron. Instead, create a proper shell script and execute the script from cron.

Answer (score 1):

The percent character `%` is a cron's own special character. It is interpreted before the text is fed to shell (so it *is* interpreted withing single quotes, etc.). You need to escape it inside crontab with backslash `\%`